# Nginx PHP-FPM with single entry point and PATH_INFO

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I am trying to configure nginx with php-fpm so most requests is passed to a single php-script.

The directory layout is as following:

```
assets/...
index.php
```

I would like the urls to work like:

```
/ -> index.php
/foo -> index.php
/bar/baz?spam=ham -> index.php
/assets -> assets folder
```

`index.php` should have `PATH_INFO` set to `'/'`, `'/foo'` and `'/bar/baz'` respectively.

The closest configuration I've figured out is the following:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php/$uri$is_args$args;
}

location /assets {
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location /index.php {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

However, `PATH_INFO` always have an additional `/` (e.g. `'//'` in the first case). Changing to `/index.php$url$is_args$args` works for all cases except for `/` which results in 404.

I could of course modify the script to handle the extra `/` but it feels a bit dirty.

I've been trying to search and reading the manual but I cant figure it out, any pointers?

Comment: I cannot see where the 404 comes from, unless it is coming from `/index.php` itself. What regular expression do you use to extract PATH_INFO (is it in `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` or `fastcgi_params`)?

Comment: `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` (default from debian) contains `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;`. The 404 is the default nginx page. Any way to debug `try_files` to see what it tries to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You commented that your `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` contains:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
```

Which you will notice, does not match the URI `/index.php/`, which explains why you get a 404 response.

You can override the value in `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` by placing the corrected statement after it (assuming that you do not want to edit the system file). For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$uri$is_args$args;
}
location /index.php {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Simply change the `+` to a `*` so that `/` is matched when nothing else follows it.